# Mobile app client-server operations, pusher or just code it?

Tags: mobile, client-server, pusher

I'm starting an app, and am facing a big doubt.

**Relevant info on the app:**

1. Users can chat (p2p, or via server)
2. Users queue before chatting (i.e omegle, chatroulette, wakie, etc)
   Basically, these is the client-server operations of the app. I was
   searching for ways to implement this, to not reinvent the wheel, and
   so i found Pusher and Quickblox.

**Pusher:** This is where i have doubts. I need one server to send events to clients, another server to listen to client events via webhook, and yet another server to handle authentication. Though i suppose everything can be on the same server, havent tried this.

**Quickblox:** to use for chatting, looks good enough, no doubts here for now.

Minus chatting, the only network operation is the queueing, which should be very simple, thus i am left wondering if this is the proper course.

Since these decisions have a major impact on the project (i shiver at the thought of having to rollback), I thought i would ask for some opinions here.

Answer (score 0):

This is my opinion about pusher since I only know pusher.

I'm in the midst of writing my app using pusher now for 1 to 1 chat. (And you can have everything on the same server. )

Implementation is easy, including client events, authentication etc and we do not need to bother about maintaining the infrastructure.

**The problem I've encountered over the course of my project is cost.** For just sending of messages between 2 person, every time you send a message you are using up 2 message credits minimum(one to the channel, one to subscriber). This is fine, but if you want to create feature like read status, delivery status, and 'user is typing' status, the number of messages adds up very quickly if you have to use 2 message credit for every of such simple client event.

Hence if you have cost consideration like I do, what I did was to use pusher for more critical feature like sending messages in a 1-1 chat and checking whether user are online. On the other side I am planning to use Slanger or other similar pusher self hosted solutions to implement other features like delivery status, read status, and 'user typing' status which I feel are good to have but not as mission critical as sending/receiving the messages itself.

I've read a lot on pusher.com and their pricing is quite reasonable comparing to building and managing the architecture myself, and their service is reliable so far. So it depends on how mission critical is your app.